# QMK Proton-C decoupling capacitors

Tags: microcontroller, decoupling-capacitor

I'm designing a keyboard with the Proton-C and I'm not sure about using decoupling capacitors - how to connect them.

It has 3 GND pins, 1 VCC/3.3V pin and 1 VBUS (5V_RAW) pin (if I'm looking at it correctly.) Do I use 2 decoupling capacitors, one connecting VBUS to GND and the other VCC to GND and then if something needs to be connected to GND/VCC/VBUS I connect it through those capacitors? I'm pretty confused to be honest.

[image: A picture of the pinout provided my QMK in Eeschema]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module has its own decoupling capacitors. Unless the module datasheet suggests otherwise, any extras are for whatever you connect. You've not detailed what else is being connected.

If you use both the 5V and 3.3V, you may need two capacitors, maybe more. You've not detailed what else there is - you could have 20 WS2812 leds which should have a capacitor for each led located as close as possible to each led.

Comment: > Unless the module datasheet suggests otherwise,
The problem being - cant find the datasheet anywhere, pretty much doesnt exist.
Im only asking for the decoupling capacitors, any other capacitors are a given depending on the component.
Thanks

Comment: @cztrollolcz, if you are "designing" the device for your private use, you can connect any capacitors you wish, within reason. But if you want to design a device for mass production, you should not be using components with no specifications.